# app authentication

Tags: security, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [securing connection to php server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670312/securing-connection-to-php-server)

I'm writing an mobile application to access an online database (I'm more interested in the high-level algorithm/protocol than the platform-specific implementation).

Since keeping the DB updated require a lot of work I want to restrict the access to my sponsored application only (I don't want other apps to take advantage of my DB for free). To do this I need to authenticate the application itself, but how can I do it?

If I store some sort of credentials within the app somebody could try to disassemble the program, retrieve the data and write his own application bypassing mine (even if I encrypt the credentials I still need to store somewhere the decryption key...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is employ mutually-authenticated SSL, so that your server will only accept incoming connections from your app and your app will only communicate with your server.

Here's the high-level approach. Create a self-signed server SSL certificate and deploy on your web server. You can use the keytool included with the Android SDK (if you're using Android; there are similar tools out there for other platforms) for this purpose. Then create a self-signed client and deploy that within your application in a custom keystore included in your application as a resource (keytool will generate this as well). Configure the server to require client-side SSL authentication and to only accept the client certificate you generated. Configure the client to use that client-side certificate to identify itself and only accept the one server-side certificate you installed on your server for that part of it.

If someone/something other than your app attempts to connect to your server, the SSL connection will not be created, as the server will reject incoming SSL connections that do not present the client certificate that you have included in your app.

A step-by-step for this is a much longer answer than is warranted here. I would suggest doing this in stages as there are resources on the web about how to deal with self-signed SSL certificate in Android, both server and client side. There is also a complete walk-through for Android applications in my book, [Application Security for the Android Platform](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022596.do), published by O'Reilly.

Now...you are right in that someone with access to the mobile app could recover the private key associated with the client-side certificate. It would be in a BKS keystore that would be encrypted but your app would need to supply a password to open that keystore. So, someone could reverse engineer your app (fairly easy on the Android platform), grab the password, grab the keystore, and decrypt it to recover the client-side private key. You can mitigate this someway by obfuscating the app to make reversing the keystore password more difficult, or asking the user to log in to the app and using that password to derive the password the the keystore, etc...it really depends on the level of risk you're willing to take on for your application.